# Can Scala projects be compiled into web application

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I'm new to Scala but I do know JAVA. Can Scala projects be compiled into web apps and deployed to Webservers like JAVA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala code is converted into byte code after compilation, hence yes it can be done.

[here](http://geotrellis.io/tutorials/webservice/spray/) this should help for starting